# save column values into two columns based on length

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to split values from table based on length.
I have table where I have column with id values of technician (max 3 digits) and technician partners (5 digits). I would like to split them to two different columns technician into tech_id and partners into partners_id

```
+-----------+
|   tech    |
+-----------+
|    64     |
+-----------+
|   60008   |
+-----------+
| 127;50047 |
+-----------+
|   ....    |
+-----------+
```

I tried something like this, but I get incorrect syntax near ')'. line 3

```
SELECT (CASE
       WHEN LEN(tech) > 4
       ) AS partners_id ,
       (CASE
        WHEN LEN(tech)< 4
       ) AS tech_id
FROM database
```

Thank you for your advice. And how does this query work with values delimited by ;?

Comment: I think you forgot `END CASE` please add `END CASE` and try again

Comment: see true `case` synatax... `case when len(tech)>4 THEN tech END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT IFNULL((CASE WHEN length(tech) > 4 THEN tech END),'') AS partners_id ,
       IFNULL((CASE WHEN length(tech)< 4 THEN tech END),'') AS tech_id
FROM database;
```

Comment: thank you, but getting 'ntext' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: you means `length` is not a recognized ?

Comment: it looks so ..I needed to do it `SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(U_Partner) > 4 THEN U_Partner ELSE '' END AS partners_id ,
       CASE WHEN LEN(U_Partner) <= 4 THEN U_Partner ELSE '' END AS tech_id

FROM [XXX].[dbo].[@COR_SC_EQUIP]` But I am getting this error msg

Comment: sorry was to post bellow..but even IFNULL ((CASE ... its not working giving the same error

Comment: I am using MYSQL and this query working fine in my local i have tested too.

Comment: 'length' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Are you using MYSQL ?

Comment: they used text not int because sometimes you need  ; in value to delimited

Comment: and if I would like to have something like  WHEN LEN(U_Partner) > 4 THEN U_Partner ELSE '' END AS partners_id `AND put static id '9999' into tech_id .. so basically, when there is long id put it to different column and save to tech static id`

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax of CASE statement is as below

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(tech) > 4 THEN tech ELSE '' END AS partners_id ,
       CASE WHEN LENGTH(tech) <= 4 THEN tech ELSE '' END AS tech_id

FROM database
```

Based on length of value in tech column `partners_id` column will either be blank if length is smaller than 4 or have value as `tech` column value. Same goes for `tech_id` column based on its condition of length being less than 4.

As per comment below of jarlh if **ELSE** part is ignored **NULL** value will be contained in `partner_id` and `tech_id` column if their respective conditions are not met in `CASE` statement

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(tech) > 4 THEN tech  END AS partners_id ,
       CASE WHEN LENGTH(tech) <= 4 THEN tech END AS tech_id

FROM database
```

Comment: Don't use empty strings instead if null. Simply skip the ELSE's.

Comment: I got  _'ntext' is not a recognized built-in function name._

Comment: i havent used ntext anywhere in  my answer , source of error is somewhere else in your complete code

Answer (score 1):

Try a union

```
select TECH as PARTNERS_ID, '' as TECH_ID
from database -- bad name here
where length(TECH) > 4
union
select '' as PARTNERS_ID, TECH as TECH_ID
from database 
where length(TECH) <= 4
```

Comment: I recommend UNION ALL here. And don't use empty strings instead if null.

Comment: no ..get 'ntext' is not a recognized built-in function name.